# How to put a line number every line of algorithmic

Tags: algorithms, line-numbering

I am looking for a way to have a number for every line in `algorithmic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Some alg}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \REQUIRE a,b, c
            \STATE d = a + b + c
            \STATE d = d/2
            \STATE d = d/3
            \RETURN d
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have:

```
 Require: a,b,c
1 d = a + b + c
2 d = a + b + c
3 d = d/2
4 d = d/3
  return d
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf) you can do this the following way:

> An optional argument to the `\begin{algorithmic}` statement can be used to turn on line numbering by giving a positive integer indicating the required frequency of line numbering. For example, `\begin{algorithmic}[5]` would cause every fifth line to be numbered.

Obviously, `\begin{algorithmic}[1]` causes a number for every line.

Comment: Is there any way to enable/disable line numbering for each `algorithmic` environment?