# Indent text but not numbers using latex

Tags: indentation, algorithms

So, basically, what I'm trying to do is have an ordered list describing pseudocode. But I want the numbers of each step to be aligned but the text I want indented.

I'm using R-studio and am very new to Latex, so I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

Below is an example of the code I'm using:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]

{\textbf{Algorithm} {EXAMPLE}}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Line 1
\item line 2
\setlength\itemindent{25pt} \item line 3
\item line 4
\setlength\itemindent{55pt} \item  line 5
\item line 6
\setlength\itemindent{25pt} \item line 7
\item line 8
\setlength\itemindent{0pt} \item line 9
\item line 10

\end{enumerate}
\end{algorithm}
```

This produces an output like this:

[image: Indented numbers]

However, I would like to have all the numbers aligned but keep the text indented.

Any suggestions as to how I'd solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! So you want line numbering instead of an ordered list?

Comment: I'm not sure... I literally started learning Latex today... so I don't know any of the terms yet

Comment: Line numbering is no TeX term but is a concept which involves having a number n at the beginning of the line where n of the first line is (mostly) 1 and n of the successor of this line is n+1. Do you want to start each line with a line number?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18111/how-to-put-a-line-number-every-line-of-algorithmic

Comment: The distance between the number and the text is set by \labelsep, but it moves the number to the left, not the text to the right.  You would have to increase \labelwidth by the same amount.

Answer (score 1):

How about this way?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The \LaTeX\ preamble of this example.}
\begin{minted}[linenos,bgcolor=orange!05]{latex}
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{minted}
        \floatstyle{ruled}
        \newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}
        \floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\end{minted}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're after something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\let\oldState\State
\renewcommand{\State}[1][0]{%
  \oldState\hspace*{#1\dimexpr\algorithmicindent\relax}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Example}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Line 1
    \State Line 2
      \State[1] Line 3
      \State[1] Line 4
        \State[2] Line 5
        \State[2] Line 6
      \State[1] Line 7
      \State[1] Line 8
    \State Line 9
    \State Line 10
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

An update to the `\State` macro makes it accept an option argument for indenting that line by a multiple of `\algorithmicindent`. This won't look acceptable if the line of code is longer than the text width though.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, however, I just can't get it to work for me. I'm using R-Markdown and knitting to a pdf. I've been following some guides on using Latex in R-markdown, but to no success.  I'm very new to Latex and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. I was putting this into the header      `---
title: "My Title"
author: me
output: pdf_document
documentclass: article
header-includes:
- \usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,xfp}
---` And then just pasting your code to see if I can get it to run... but no success

Comment: @egreg: You should try it...

Comment: @Electrino: You need the redefinition of `\State` as well. For that, add the `\let` and `\renewcommand` components to a file (say) `mymacros.tex`, save it in your working forlder and add `\input{mymacros}` to your `header-includes` clause.

Comment: @Werner You should use `#1\dimexpr\algorithmicindent\relax`