# Does anybody know how to draw this pseudo code diagram?

Tags: tables, pseudocode

I want to draw this pseudo code in latex, can anybody help me?

[image]

This is the code I created, however, it somehow doesn't match the requirement, can anybody help me to modify the code?

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{elsarticle}
%
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[htb]
\caption{GraphSAGE embedding generation (i.e., forward propagation) algorithm}
\label{alg:algorithm1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require
      Graph G ($\Gamma$, $\Xi$); input features \{{$x_v$, \forall{$v$} \in $\Gamma$}\}; depth $K$; weight matrices $W^k, \forall{k} \in \{1, ...,K\}$; non-linearity $\sigma$; differentiable aggregator functions $AGGREGATE_k$
      
    \Ensure
      Vector representations $z_v$ \forall{v} \in $\Gamma$;
    \State $h^0_v$ \leftarrow $x_v$, \forall{$v$} \in $\Gamma$
    \label{code:fram:extract}
    \For{$k = 1...K$}
        \For{$v \in \Gamma$}
        \State $h^k_N(v)$ \leftarrow $AGGREGATE_k$ (\{$h^{k-1}_u, \forall{u} \in $N(v)$\});
        
        $h^{k-1} \leftarrow $\sigma$ $(W^k \cdot CONCAT(h^{k-1}_v, h^{k}_{N(v)})) 
        \EndFor
        \\
        $h^k_v$ \leftarrow $h^k_v$ $h^k_v$, \forall{v} \in $\Gamma$
        \EndFor
        
        \State $z_v$ \leftarrow $h_v^K$, \forall{v} \in $\Gamma$;
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Make your choise: https://ctan.org/topic/pseudocode , e.g. algorithmicx . // It may be a good idea to seach for those packages here. This simple probing gives you a quick idea, how capable each package is, if it serves your needs etc.

Comment: Better if you do not manage the  algorithms like figures but as a new float type, like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456494/11604).